# Setup Xdebug on local webserver (xampp) and php 7?

Tags: php, netbeans, xampp, xdebug, netbeans-8

I try to get started with [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org) for multiple hours without success.

First I determined which php_xdebug.dll version I need by visiting this [official link](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php), and followed their instructions.

```
Summary
Xdebug installed: 2.6.0
Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC15 - Architecture: x86
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 7.2.3
Zend API nr: 320170718
PHP API nr: 20170718
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: yes
Configuration File Path: C:\WINDOWS
Configuration File: A:\xampp\php\php.ini
Extensions directory: A:\xampp\php\ext
You're already running the latest Xdebug version
But here are the instructions anyway:

1. Download php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.2-vc15.dll
2. Move the downloaded file to A:\xampp\php\ext
3. Update A:\xampp\php\php.ini and change the line
   zend_extension = A:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.2-vc15.dll
4. Restart the webserver
```

This is my `php.ini` snippet:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension="A:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.2-vc15.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "A:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.remote_log = "A:\xampp\tmp\xdebug\xdebug.log"
xdebug.idekey = "netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_autostart = on
xdebug.remote_connect_back = on
```

I set the `port` and `idekey` in netbeans accordingly (Tools -> Options -> PHP -> Debugging).

[image]

...I also made sure that the project is using the settings (Project -> Properties -> Run Configuration)

[image]

I restarted NetBeans and Apache.
I even installed the extension "Xdebug helper" and "NetBeans Connector".
The Xdebug helper extension is already configured and set to debug mode.

---

Now I set a breakpoint. But I get "Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)" after right clicking in the source code and clicking on "Debug File", and it is loading forever.

[image]

I also can't click on the debug buttons, they are all grayed out:

[image]

I always call the target site with the following parameter, like instructed in the [official documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/all#activate_debugger): `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug`

---

I tried different solutions from other questions on SO, but nothing helped.

I already tried to change the line `xdebug.remote_host` in php.ini to my local ipv4 address, it made no difference. I also tested different ports. Of course I always restarted apache after changing something in the php.ini.

I am using Windows 10 Pro 64 bit and Chrome.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help!

---

More:

I checked my firewall, the port is not being blocked.

Comment: What xdebug log has to say about it? *"I already tried to change the line xdebug.remote_host"* It will make no difference since you have `xdebug.remote_connect_back = on` (it will ignore remote_host in most cases)

Comment: @LazyOne, I commented `xdebug.remote_connect_back = on` out after changing `xdebug.remote_host`. The log showed that it tried to connect to random ip addresses!! Thats because of the chrome extension "ipflood" (ipfuck). After disabling the extension it works!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it thanks to @LazyOne's hint. After checking the logs I found out, that netbeans tried to connect to random ip addresses:

```
Log opened at 2018-04-10 21:14:12
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 74.84.178.15:9001.
E: Time-out connecting to client (Waited: 200 ms). :-(
Log closed at 2018-04-10 21:14:12

Log opened at 2018-04-10 21:17:27
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 212.112.65.234:9001.
E: Time-out connecting to client (Waited: 200 ms). :-(
Log closed at 2018-04-10 21:17:27

Log opened at 2018-04-10 21:19:22
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 57.101.242.52:9001.
E: Time-out connecting to client (Waited: 200 ms). :-(
Log closed at 2018-04-10 21:19:22
```

I instantly knew that this has something to do with the chrome extension `ipflood` which is changing the ip addresses randomly. It works after disabling it!